# Finding the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I have done part i by putting $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ into a matrix and the putting that matrix intro REF to find value of constants $c_1$ to $c_4$

But for the next part how do i find the dimension of $W$ and a basis for $W$?
(Also in general how do you find the dimension of a vector space)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is the number of elements in its basis. When you put the matrix in REF, what solutions did you get for the constants? The number of free parameters is the number of basis elements is the dimension of the subspace.

Comment: @Cameron Williams: I get c1 = -1, c2 =-2, c3 = 1 and c4 = 1, sorry i didn't quite understand what you meant by free parameters

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ as columns of the matrix, assume $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ to be row vectors so that $v_1$ forms the first row of the matrix and so on. Now reduce the matrix to it's row echelon form.
The number of non-zero rows is the dimension of W.
And the non zero rows would form a basis of W.